# Thread safety/Transaction enforcer

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, c++14

I have some legacy classes written without thread safety in mind. Instances of these classes are now being accessed in a multithreaded context in a thread-un-safe manner. Cue chaos.

To fix this I make a wrapper class that enforces the user to take a transaction lock to serialize access to the instance.

```
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <cassert>

namespace trapi {
    template<typename T>
    class Transaction {
    public:
        Transaction(T& a_data, std::mutex& a_mutex)
            : m_data(a_data), m_lg(a_mutex)
        {}

        Transaction(T& a_data, std::mutex& a_mutex, std::adopt_lock_t)
            : m_data(a_data), m_lg(a_mutex, std::adopt_lock)
        {}

        Transaction(const Transaction&) = delete;

        Transaction(Transaction&& a_that)
            : m_data(a_that.m_data), m_lg(std::move(a_that.m_lg))
        {}

        ~Transaction() = default;

        Transaction& operator = (const Transaction& a_that) = delete;
        Transaction& operator = (Transaction&& a_that) = delete;

        T* operator -> () const {
            assert(m_owner == std::this_thread::get_id());
            return &m_data.get();
        }

    private:
        std::reference_wrapper<T> m_data;
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> m_lg;

#ifndef NDEBUG
        std::thread::id m_owner = std::this_thread::get_id();
#endif
    };

    // Starts multiple transactions simultaneously in a 
    // dead-lock free manner.
    template<typename... Args>
    auto transaction(Args&&... args) {
        std::lock(args...);
        return std::make_tuple(args.adopt_transaction()...);
    }

    template<typename T>
    class TransactionEnforcer {
    public:
        template<typename... Args>
        TransactionEnforcer(Args&&... args)
            : m_data(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
        {}

        TransactionEnforcer(const TransactionEnforcer&) = delete;
        TransactionEnforcer(TransactionEnforcer&&) = delete;
        ~TransactionEnforcer() = default;
        TransactionEnforcer& operator = (const TransactionEnforcer&) = delete;
        TransactionEnforcer& operator = (TransactionEnforcer&&) = delete;

        Transaction<T> transaction() {
            return Transaction<T>(m_data, m_mutex);
        }

        Transaction<const T> transaction() const {
            return Transaction<T>(m_data, m_mutex);
        }

        void lock() { m_mutex.lock(); }
        bool try_lock() { return m_mutex.try_lock(); }
        void unlock() { m_mutex.unlock(); }

        Transaction<T> adopt_transaction() {
            return Transaction<T>(m_data, m_mutex, std::adopt_lock);
        }

        Transaction<const T> adopt_transaction() const {
            return Transaction<T>(m_data, m_mutex, std::adopt_lock);
        }

    private:
        T m_data;
        std::mutex m_mutex;
    };
}

class ThreadUnsafeClass {
public:
    void func1() {}
    void func2() {}
};

using ThreadSafeClass = trapi::TransactionEnforcer<ThreadUnsafeClass>;

int main() {
    ThreadSafeClass data1;
    ThreadSafeClass data2;

    {
        auto t = data1.transaction();
        t->func1();
        t->func2();
    }

    {
        auto ct = trapi::transaction(data1, data2);
        auto& t1 = std::get<0>(ct);
        auto& t2 = std::get<1>(ct);
        t1->func1();
        t2->func2();
    }
}
```

In general I'm happy with the design and it will solve the problem elegantly IMHO.

But what I'm concerned about is the debug `m_owner` in the `Transaction` class. I want something to alert me when some one has managed to share a `Transaction` object between threads. But I'm not sure if this is actually a problem if it happens. Am I being to strict here?

Also the free function `transaction` that allows one to start multiple transactions without ending up in a deadlock. To be able to implement it was forced to make `lock()`, `try_lock()`, `unlock()` and `adopt_transaction()` public which I'm not happy about as I don't want the user fiddling with these and possibly breaking something by forgetting to unlock and what have you. I tried to declare the `transaction` function as a template friend but I couldn't figure out the return type. So I would like some help with that.

I'm also very keen on ideas for better names. I'm not 100% sold on the current names but I can't come up with anything better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Also the free function `transaction` that allows one to start multiple transactions without ending up in a deadlock. To be able to implement it was forced to make `lock()`, `try_lock()`, `unlock()` and `adopt_transaction()` public which I'm not happy about as I don't want the user fiddling with these and possibly breaking something by forgetting to unlock and what have you. I tried to declare the `transaction` function as a template friend but I couldn't figure out the return type. So I would like some help with that.

```
// Starts multiple transactions simultaneously in a 
// dead-lock free manner.
template<typename... Args>
auto transaction(Args&&... args) {
    std::lock(args...);
    return std::make_tuple(args.adopt_transaction()...);
}
```

First of all, I don't think this is a good use of variadic templates. IIUC, you're trying to make a function that accepts any number of `TransactionEnforcer<T>` objects and returns a `std::tuple<Transaction<T>...>`? I would express that *at least* as

```
template<typename... T>
auto transaction(TransactionEnforcer<T>&&... args) {
    std::lock(args...);
    return std::make_tuple(args.adopt_transaction()...);
}
```

and possibly throw in the `-> std::tuple<Transaction<T>...>` since it's pretty easy to express; but bearing in mind that when you provide an explicit return type you enable SFINAE on that return type, which could theoretically turn some wrong code from a compiler error ("call to `transaction` is ambiguous...") into code that happily does the wrong thing (since one of the candidates is now SFINAE'd away). That's highly theoretical, though.

Now, how do you make this function a `friend` of `TransactionEnforcer`? That's easy; just define it inline!

```
template<class T>
class TransactionEnforcer
{
    // ...

    template<typename... T>
    friend auto transaction(TransactionEnforcer<T>&&... args) {
        std::lock(args...);
        return std::make_tuple(args.adopt_transaction()...);
    }
};
```

This would allow you to make `adopt_transaction` a private member function; but it would *not* allow you to make `lock`, `try_lock`, and `unlock` private member functions, because they're still being touched by someone who's not a friend of the class; namely, they're being touched by `std::lock()`.

To fix this, you could expose a private inner class `LockView`:

```
template<class T>
class TransactionEnforcer
{
    // ...
  private:
    void lock();
    bool try_lock();
    void unlock();
    friend struct LockView {
        TransactionEnforcer& te_;
        void lock() { return te_.lock(); }
        bool try_lock() { return te_.try_lock(); }
        void unlock() { return te_.unlock(); }
    };
    LockView lock_view() { return LockView{*this}; }

    template<typename... T>
    friend auto transaction(TransactionEnforcer<T>&&... args) {
        std::lock(args.lock_view()...);
        return std::make_tuple(args.adopt_transaction()...);
    }
};
```

Unfortunately, *this* doesn't work out of the box because `std::lock()` requires that its arguments all be lvalues. So you'll have to make up some storage for the `LockView` objects somewhere: either use parameter-pack expansion to turn your parameter-pack full of TransactionEnforcers into a tuple full of LockViews suitable for passing (via `std::apply`?) to `std::lock`, or else make `te.lock_view()` return an *lvalue reference* to `te.lv_`, which is a self-referential LockView subobject of `te`. Fun times. But you *can* make it work.

No comment on the basic functionality of `TransactionEnforcer`; I'm not sure it's doing what you really want done, but maybe it is.

Comment: Thanks for the review. The design of the class does full-fill its purpose, prevents accidental non-exclusive access to the protected data in legacy code.

Answer (score -2):

I might be missing something, but from the looks of it, you are solving non-existent problem at a cost of the performance (big time). From your description it sounds like you have huge multi-threaded system where transaction objects are floating around and they are being picked up at random to be executed. If that is the case, I would concentrate on the executing part and address the thread safety there. Making a transaction object, especially small one, be "thread-safe" seems strange.

Added the simple tester, how would it look using your contraption? Will it work?

```
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <cassert>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class  ThreadUnsafeClass 
{
    public:
        void func1() { std::cout << "func1" << std::endl; }         
        void func2() { std::cout << "func2" << std::endl; }
};


class simple_tester
{

public:


    void sample_trhread_proc1()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> alock(m_data_lock);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(4));
        m_sample_transaction.func1();
    }



    void sample_trhread_proc2()
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> alock(m_data_lock);
        m_sample_transaction.func2();



    }


    void run_test()
    {
        std::thread th1(&simple_tester::sample_trhread_proc1, this);
        std::thread th2(&simple_tester::sample_trhread_proc2, this);

        if (th1.joinable())
            th1.join();
        if (th2.joinable())
            th2.join();

    }



private:
    std::mutex          m_data_lock;
    ThreadUnsafeClass   m_sample_transaction;
};


int main()
{
    simple_tester().run_test();
}
```

Comment: The problem being solved is that I need to enforce transaction semantics on legacy classes. There are no "transaction objects floating about". The comment about the thread ID was more of a prevent stupid mistakes in debug mode type of deal. The main point of this is to make sure that the user doesn't manipulate the datum without a mutex for the entire duration of the transaction.

Comment: While I like the threadID debugging technique , I simply do not understand how you are going to enforce it, moreover how you going to use **same instance** of lock in different threads. Your code is incredibly complex for what it is doing ( I would hate to be a maintenance  programmer working with it ) , yet it seems to miss the very functionality it advertises

Comment: Quite frankly you don't make much sense to me. How am I going to enforce what exactly? I'm not using the same `unique_lock` from different threads that's the whole point of the assert on the thread Id, to make sure the user doesn't do that. If you meant the `mutex` then that's the way you're supposed to use a mutex...  The code is not at all complex, quite the opposite it aims to reduce complexity of explicitly dealing with locking and automating the process in a foolproof way. You have the wrong idea of what the code accomplishes, but I can't figure out what it is you don't understand...